# How I can make my View-Extension update View with State input in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui

Here I got an extension which works fine for updating itself at lunch, but after Lunch or Appear, it does not reports the change of data to its View.

**My Goal: I want my Extension get sensitive to value that is reporting.**

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var changeString: String = "Hello, world!"
    
    var body: some View {

        customText().stringOfText(changeString).padding()
        
        Button("change") { changeString = "Omid" }.padding()
        
        Text(changeString).padding()
        
  
    }
}



struct customText: View {
    

    
    @State var stringOfText = ""
    
    var body: some View
    {
        Text(stringOfText)
            
    }
}


extension customText {
    func stringOfText(_ text: String) -> customText {
        customText(stringOfText: text)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should not be state inside, because state is not recreated, ie. you need

```
struct customText: View {
    var stringOfText: String = "" // << here !!
    
    var body: some View {
        Text(stringOfText)
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot, but I would like keep my style of coding like this: customText().stringOfText(changeString). If I use your code, then I am going loose those extension style! which is important for me.

Comment: Ok, just add default value as updated. It is tested & works with Xcode 12.1 / iOS 14.1

Comment: What? I did not understood! can you explain plz?

Comment: Well... in your `customText` view, just remove `@State` property wrapper as shown in my answer, no other changes, and give it a try.